# Why can’t I stop the MySQL service on Debian?

Tags: debian, mysql, aptitude

I just tried to upgrade from debian squeeze to unstable by replacing 'squeeze' with 'unstable' in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The upgrade went smoothly except for MySQL, which failed because it couldn't stop MySQL.

`/etc/init.d/mysql stop` simply returns that it failed, but if I try to get the status with `/etc/init.d/mysql status` it gives me this error:

```
me@debian:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

MySQL is running fine, and I checked the permissions for debian-sys-maint in phpmyadmin and it's allowed to do everything, but only connect from `localhost`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. `sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf` and look for the password listed under both the `[client]` and `[mysql_upgrade]` sections
2. `mysql -u root -p password` being the original MySQL root password
3. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '*the password obtained from step 1*';`
4. `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

That's the fix and [this](http://mirzmaster.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/mysql-access-denied-for-user-debian-sys-maintlocalhost/) is the reasoning behind it, if you're interested.

Comment: As mentioned below, this should be `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*`

Answer (score 2):

An update to the answer. In step 3, I had to use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'the password obtained from step 1';
```

There are asterisks around the period after "ON".  Worked for MySql 5.1

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL Reference Manual [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) you can do this:

1. Log on to your system as the Unix user that the `mysqld` server runs as (for example, `mysql`).
2. Locate the `.pid` file that contains the server's process ID. The exact location and name of this file depend on your distribution, host name, and configuration. Common locations are `/var/lib/mysql/`, `/var/run/mysqld/`, and `/usr/local/mysql/data/`. Generally, the file name has an extension of `.pid` and begins with either `mysqld` or your system's host name.

You can stop the MySQL server by sending a normal kill (not kill -9) to the mysqld process, using the path name of the .pid file in the following command:

```
    kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`
```

This part: `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid` returns the contents of the file, which is the process id.